# FFmpeg can't convert MOV to FLV

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, quicktime

When i try to convert a .mov file to .flv i get this type of output.

I get error

> Invalid sample format '(null)' Error opening filters!.

When I convert .avi or .mp4 I get no errors. I'm on Windows.

```
ffmpeg -i C:/wamp/www/\ds_uploads\62\video\23c4a54cbf8bc73056cb370ae7371848.mov -y -f flv -ar 44100 -q:v 0 C:/wamp/www/\ds_uploads\62\video\23c4a54cbf8bc73056cb370ae7371848.flv 2>&1
ffmpeg version N-47062-g26c531c Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 25 2012 12:21:26 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libutvideo --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52.  9.100 / 52.  9.100
  libavcodec     54. 77.100 / 54. 77.100
  libavformat    54. 37.100 / 54. 37.100
  libavdevice    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 23.102 /  3. 23.102
  libswscale      2.  1.102 /  2.  1.102
  libswresample   0. 17.101 /  0. 17.101
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 01f8b200] multiple edit list entries, a/v desync might occur, patch welcome
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 01f8b200] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5015510
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:/wamp/www/\ds_uploads\62\video\23c4a54cbf8bc73056cb370ae7371848.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 1998-11-04 16:40:13
  Duration: 00:01:00.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 110 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: svq1 (SVQ1 / 0x31515653), yuv410p, 160x120, 90 kb/s, 7.51 fps, 7.50 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1998-11-04 16:40:13
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: qdmc (QDMC / 0x434D4451), 44100 Hz, mono
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1998-11-04 16:40:13
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
[graph 1 input from stream 0:1 @ 02b5f040] Invalid sample format '(null)'
Error opening filters!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ffmpeg can not decode the first version QDesign Music Codec (QDMC) audio, although it can decode QDM2:

```
$ ffmpeg -codecs
 D..... = Decoding supported
 .E.... = Encoding supported
 ..V... = Video codec
 ..A... = Audio codec
 ..S... = Subtitle codec
 ...I.. = Intra frame-only codec
 ....L. = Lossy compression
 .....S = Lossless compression

 D.A.L. qdm2                 QDesign Music Codec 2
 ..A.L. qdmc                 QDesign Music
```

Also see [Multimedia Wiki: QDesign Music Codec](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=QDesign_Music_Codec). You may be able to decode the audio with `mplayer` (with w32codecs support) and then pipe the output to ffmpeg for encoding. (Example commands would be a good edit for this answer).